# Does the Parasympathetic Tract of Colon Sigmoideum Travel with Nervus Vagus and its Nucleus Dorsalis Nervi Vagi?

Tags: neuroscience, cranial-nerves

I have the following tractus now:

> nucleus parasymphaticus sacrales -> nervus splanchnic -> ganglion
>   terminalis -> colon sigmoideum

The tract is parasympathetic.
It suggests me that it should travel along CN 9 or CN 10, most likely with CN 10.

**Does tractus colon sigmoideum travel with CN 10 and its nucleus dorsalis nervi vagi?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following from [Wikipedia](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aBzi3WZBH4rMJ%3aen.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_colon%20&cd=1&hl=fi&ct=clnk&gl=fi):

> Pelvic splanchnic nerves are the primary source for parasympathetic innervation [for Sigmoid colon].

The non-cranial nerve is extending the scope of the cranial nerve by a synapse between the two neurons. The neurons are transmitting the electrical impulse from one neuron to another.
So this way the splanchnic nerve does not need to be with CN 10 in the region of impact.

The parasympathetic tract of colon sigmoideum can travel with nervus vagus by having a synapse between pelvic splanchnic nerve and CN 10. I verified this from my professor.