# Are CN3, CN7, CN9 and CN10 the only Parasympathetic Cranial Nerves?

Tags: neuroscience, anatomy

It has been my thought for a long time that this is the case, but I am unsure currently, since the parasympathetic tract of colon sigmoideum does not seem to have connection with CN 10. It connects with pelvic splanchnic nerves. 
Discussion about it [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1632/does-the-parasympathetic-tract-of-colon-sigmoideum-travel-with-nervus-vagus-and).

If there is no connection from pelvic splanchnic nerves to CN 10, like CN 10 running within the nerves, then my though must be wrong.

**Are CN3, CN7, CN9 and CN10 the only Parasympathetic Cranial Nerves?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, only III, VII, IX, and X are cranial nerves that carry parasympathetic autonomic neurons. The key phrase is "cranial." Pelvic splanchnic nerves also carry parasympathetics, but they arise from the pelvis, not the brain.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused by the definition of the word itself "cranial". Parasympathetic Cranial Nerve only means parasympathetic neurons that arise from the brain. So the elements of brainstem like the lower parts of Medulla Oblongata still belongs to the brain.